# Ket notation in alternate forms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra, quantum-states

I have been told that I can describe a system by its wave number states:
$$|k_1\rangle|k_2\rangle,$$
and that the following is true:
$$|k_1\rangle|k_2\rangle=|k_1+k_2\rangle|k_1-k_2\rangle,$$
I am aware that the ket notation represents vectors but I am not too familiar with it, I was just wondering if this is some form of the dot product and if there is some way to put a system such as:
$$|k_1\rangle|k_2\rangle|k_3\rangle,$$
In a similar form?

Comment: Using 2d vectors for illustration, and assuming you are writing down a tensor product informally, you may illustrate that this equality fails, resoundingly. (Do it!) There must be more to what you have been told. This is not some kind of a dot product.

Comment: Be careful:  $\langle k_1 | k_2 \rangle$ is a dot product, but $|k_1\rangle |k_2 \rangle$ is a tensor product, which is ommiting the symbol $\otimes$

Comment: You should specify where you found the second equation and/or give some context, because as written it is completely false.

Comment: I may be wrong in assuming you are talking about $|k_1\rangle \otimes |k_2\rangle$, when you might well be considering a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)   $|k_1\rangle \oplus |k_2\rangle$ in a highly *nonstandard* elision, ie, your $k_1$ is an *x* axis vector, and your  $k_2$ is a *y* axis vector.  In that case, a 45 degree rotation of bases would give you something evocative of your equality. Needless to say, in physics one hardly ever uses such idiosyncratic notations...